# Как поменять цвет текста при наведении на него указателя мыши?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Для обычных объектов событие наведения на объект меняет его цвет, а для обычного текстового поля не работает.

Comment: Напишите как вы прописываете это

Comment: function OnMouseEnter() {
   renderer.material.color =Color.red;
}

Comment: Попробуйте , менять материал текста

Comment: текст UI или Mesh?

Comment: Text Mesh использую

Comment: function OnMouseEnter() { Material mat = renderer.material;mat.color =Color.red; renderer.material=mat; }

Comment: void OnMouseEnter(){ //do something }

Answer (score 1):

Непосредственно "вхождение" мышки обрабатывается при вхождении курсора в коллайдер объекта. У всех остальных примитивов в Unity коллайдеры создаются по умолчанию, кроме Text Mesh.

Просто добавьте компонент коллайдера вручную. Например, BoxCollider. Он сам подстроится под размеры вашего текста.

[Документация по MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter()](http://MonoBehaviour.OnMouseEnter())